# How to retrieve an integer value from a database for use in an IF statement

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to detect what price category these movies are in a database(either category 1,2,or 3) and I can't figure out how to read the values.

```
using (SQLiteCommand getPrice = new SQLiteCommand("select Category FROM Movies WHERE MovieID LIKE @id", conn))
{
    getPrice.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", movieid);
    using (var CategoryReader = getPrice.ExecuteReader())
    {
        int category = CategoryReader.GetInt32(1);
        if (category==1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("That is price category 1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you run this code line by line you can see the value of each variable.  That should help you.

Comment: If it's only one value, use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExexcuteReader`. If you are using a dataReader, you need to call it's `Read` method before you can access values.

Comment: when you have time, also read up about `Reader.HasRows` also you may want to use the name of the column you are looking for the value vs  the `CategoryReader.GetInt32(1)` what if the table structure changed and Category column index changed..? something to think about..

Comment: That GetInt32(1) with only one column will fail in any case.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for GetInt32 quite clearly states that the parameter is a zero-based ordinal.  So you're asking for the 2nd column of data when you've only selected one.

Comment: this is correct , not to mention other things wrong with the OP's question as well as approach..